# Why is natural logarithm abbreviated to ln?

Tags: abbreviations, mathematics

In mathematics, the natural logarithm operator is abbreviated as *ln*. There is no letter *n* in the word *logarithm*, so why do we abbreviate in this way?

Comment: Duplicate not only of [Why is the natural logarithm represented by ln?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/2762/4961) on [hsm.se] but also of [How did the notation “ln” for “log base e” become so pervasive?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1694/25361) on [math.se].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't about the English language. Besides, it is already answered on HSM.

Comment: The real reason is that engineers and others use _log_ to mean "base-10 logarithm", so that _log 2_ would be a different number than _ln 2_ because _log_ and _ln_ are different functions, with different values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [BetterExplained.com](https://betterexplained.com/articles/demystifying-the-natural-logarithm-ln/):

> Speaking of fancy, the Latin name is *logarithmus naturali[s]*, giving
>   the abbreviation ln.

[MathematicsSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1694/how-did-the-notation-ln-for-log-base-e-become-so-pervasive) has the question 'How did the notation **ln** for log base e become so pervasive?'. Dan Velleman posts:

> ... Wikipedia claims that the ln notation was invented by Stringham in
>   1893. I have seen this claim in other places as well. However, I recently came across an earlier reference. In 1875, in his book
>   Lehrbuch der Mathematik, Anton Steinhauser suggested denoting the
>   natural logarithm of a number a by "log. nat. a (spoken: logarithmus
>   naturalis a) or ln. a" (p. 277). This lends support to the theory that
>   "ln" stands for "logarithmus naturalis."

There is little there in the way of an answer to *why* the usage became well established.

Comment: I'm 50% convinced that this belongs on Maths rather than here.

Comment: Why did the usage become well established? It used to be that in scientific (not necessarily mathematical) literature, log *a* stood for log base 10. So a different notation for log base e was necessary. See the Math.SE question quoted in the answer above. Why did we chose ln instead of something else? Maybe ln was suggested first.

Comment: I am only 2.718281828459+ % sure.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth or [HSM](https://hsm.stackexchange.com) for that matter.

Comment: @Spencer Yes, that seems an even better fit. Though both have a 'terminology' tag. ... They can bunfight over terrirory.